# Number of partitions of [8] into 2 blocks of different sizes

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

**Question:**

What is the number of partitions of $[8]$ into two blocks, in which the two blocks do not have the same size? (where $[8]$ denotes the set $\{1,2,\dots,8\}$)

So the word "partitions" leads me to believe the Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind are involved, namely $S(8,2)$ and then applying some inclusion-exclusion principles to subtract out the bad ones (I'm not too certain how though), but what I was wondering is if this problem can be solved by simply adding ${{8}\choose{1}} + {{8}\choose{2}} + {{8}\choose{3}}$ since the only options are to partition the set into parts of 1 and 7, 2 and 6, or 3 and 5, since the parts cannot have the same size. Is the latter method correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Blocks do not have the same size-?

Comment: Also, are empty blocks allowed?

Comment: I do not believe empty blocks are allowed, and I think "same size" refers to cardinality of the blocks.

Comment: Then your solution seems fine to me

Answer (score 1):

Your considerations are fine and we can verify it by calculating it the other way round. The number of partitions of $[8]$ into two non-empty blocks with unequal size is the number ${8\brace 2}$ of all partitions of $[8]$ into two non-empty blocks minus the number $\frac{1}{2}\binom{8}{4}$ of two equal sized blocks.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \binom{8}{1}+\binom{8}{2}+\binom{8}{3}&=8+28+56=92\\
> {8\brace 2}-\frac{1}{2}\binom{8}{4}&=127-\frac{1}{2}\cdot70=92
> \end{align*}